# JButton text changes when an Action is set

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am working on a swing GUI project and i have a `JButton` that turns text inside a `JTextPane` bold. I use an `Action` to do this.

Here's the code for the `Action`

```
public static Action boldAction = new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction();
```

Here's the code for the `JButton`

```
JButton bold = new JButton("B");
bold.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
bold.setBounds(393, 15, 100, 100);
bold.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
bold.setAction(boldAction);
frame.add(bold);
```

Without the `Action` included the text on the button is a bold "B", which is what I want. The issue that arises is that when I add in the action, it changes the text on the button to say "font-bold".

Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

Comment: `bold.setBounds(393, 15, 100, 100);` 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Action's are self contained units of work, which include the NAME of the action which is used by buttons to set their text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an Action the properties of the Action are defaulted to the button.

If you don't want "font-bold" then you need to change the text AFTER setting the Action:

```
JButton bold = new JButton( boldAction);
bold.setText("B");
```

Also don't use the setBounds() method. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

```
//bold.setBounds(393, 15, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks, i had just thought to try that. I use the `setBounds()` only because it is so much easier to layout things, but i understand what you're saying

Answer (score 1):

The actions provided by `StyledEditorKit` alter the `Document` model belonging to  the view provided by subclasses of `JTextComponent`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513). To change the font used by a `JButton`, use the `UIManager` to change the property having the key `"Button.font"`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3445827/230513).

Because you want to change the button's appearance dynamically, use the `UIManager` to obtain the button's expected font and specify a derived font in the button's `Action`, as shown below:

[image]

```
final JButton button = new JButton();
Action action = new AbstractAction("Bold") {
    Font font = (Font) UIManager.get("Button.font");

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
    }
};
button.setAction(action);
```